# How to merge and keep my changes?

Tags: git, merge

I am working on a project where the source is delivered to me as a zipped archive. Currently, it's in version 1.0 and I have a series of patches to it in my Git repository. Yesterday, I received version 2 of the source and I need to upgrade.  I am having difficultly incorporating the new code without having it wipe out my patched up code. It ignores my changes without giving me the opportunity to perform a merge.

I have tried in vain to merge/rebase the code and it has failed. I've been trying to splice version 2.0 at a time (order?) between the unmodified version 1.0 and my modifications so that all my modifications commits are replayed onto version 2:

1. Checkout the very first commit which has version 1.0 code with no modifications. This causes a detached head.
2. Create a new branch called version 2.0
3. Copy/Replace all the files from the version 2.0 over the version 1.0 files
4. Perform a Merge back to master (unfortunately, there's no way to specify where in the chain of commits you want it to merge into.)

I tried to use rebase and it gives me the same issues. I usually get so frustrated and confused, I just blow out my repository and clone it again. I can't seem to get a grip on how Git merges. Does it use the date on the files? Is it based on the direction of the merge? If so, what direction means what?  Also, who's "theirs" and "ours"?

*ASIDE*:
Git is so confusing and frustrating that I haven't been able to get any work done for 2 weeks trying to grasp unbelievably difficult product. I dread programming because I have to knock my head up against it. Git in my experience is far more difficult to comprehend than any development tool or language I have ever used. It makes C++ look like BASIC in comparison. Git feels like I am using a raw source control API rather than a packaged product. I've tried using various GUIs and they are all thin window dressing over painful to swallow gruel.

Comment: Git brings a lot of tools and getting a grip can be overwhelming. Keep in mind that git is just software and as such, it's dumb. You still need to know what you're doing. Spend some time to get used to the tool, get training, buy a book.

Comment: The key to mastering git is to remember that it's just a tree of commits, with Post-it notes attached (references). Also, see my profile (in the bottom) for various resources that you can use to learn how to use git. In particular, I recommend the free online book Pro Git. I spent 1-3 months reading the whole thing 1 hour at a time on my way to and from work on the subway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recipe should work:

1. Checkout the version that base the base of the new sources (i.e. the common ancestor).
2. Create a new branch `release-2.0`
3. Delete the sources **Do not commit**
4. Unpack the ZIP archive with the sources
5. Add and commit all the files

You have now a repository with two branches. At the tips of these branches, you have two versions.

1. Checkout `master`
2. Merge with `release-2.0`

That will probably give you a lot of conflicts. Try to solve as many of them as possible but it's probably impossible to solve them all. The problem here is that you try to merge two things that have changed in unpredictable ways, so git really can't help you much. People have added, deleted and renamed files without telling git, so what do you expect?

If something breaks, use `git reset --merge` to undo the merge (there is no need to create the second branch again). Note: Reset only works until the merge was committed.

If that turns out to be too much work, you'll have to merge manually. That means:

`git merge --strategy ours` while you have `master` checked out. That will create a new repo with the content of `master` but which **thinks** `master` and `release-2.0` have been merged when in fact nothing has happened.

That doesn't help you much but now Git sees files with the same paths as "this is the same file". You can then look in the history, compare the contents and merge them manually.

In the future, make sure that everyone involved in the project uses Git so all changes get recorded properly. Without this information, no tool in the world can do a proper merge.

Comment: Aaron, you should write a book on Git. This is very good! What common ancestor do I choose?  The very first commit has version 1.0 files. If I branch from this commit and delete the files, doesn't it create a change set? I am assuming you want to start from an empty state with no added files.

Comment: I just assumed it could handle such a case because it's hyped as the panacea to all version control problems. So once you get down to it, the Git emperor wears no clothes. Lot's of chatter but doesn't fundamentally solve problems that all version control systems have. If it does a better job, it's really hard to tell until you've managed to make it over the learning curve. Git really sucks!

Comment: This is completely unrelated to Git; no VCS can handle this case very well.

Comment: As to your first question: No, you can start in any state that you think makes sense. But since Git has no good idea about all the things that changed, you'll have to do that in your head. All VCS depend very much on the fast "commit often, commit early" to keep the possible set of changes small.

Comment: So how do I create a common ancestor such that it starts with an empty directory of files?

Comment: The best way to do that is to create a new repository. While Git has some tools to "rewrite history", they're only suitable for people who know what they're doing.

Comment: Wow! I just figured out that Git works just like SVN and all the other ones out there. Just another way to get you from point A to B with a few more options.

Comment: Git took all the good things from SVN and found solutions for the bad ones like having to merge *before* you can commit. With git, you can commit (and thus save your work) and *then* try to merge. If something breaks, Git can always go back to a clean/safe state.

Comment: Thank you. i come to that conclusion myself too. We have to use a common starting point. The procedure is ready

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your use-case is close to the hotfix scenario (if you treat the version 2.0. as a hotfix) described in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Check the following figures

1. Figure 3-13. hotfix branch based back at your master branch point.
2. Figure 3-14. Your master branch points to the same place as your hotfix branch after the merge.
3. Figure 3-16. Git automatically identifies the best common-ancestor merge base for branch merging.

Comment: NO!!! Please don't send me to another crappy explanation of how to use Git! I tried to sit down and read that site and it didn't make any sense. Obviously, many people agree with me otherwise it wouldn't be a free book.